# jquery simple regex search for substring included

Tags: jquery, regex, substring

I'm trying out a very simple regex, and my question is that I just need to make sure that if is one of the following terms is found in the `data-title` of my `div`, then the alert says so: `Person Name, Email, Title` and a few more strings.

I've used a few combinations but I haven't been able to do it... so I've made a fiddle here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLdWD/), I've just removed my regex attempts apart from the `|`, so I've left only the main phrases I want to catch. Could someone please help? I know it could be done using substring or indexOf but I want to do it with regex.

JS:

```
title = $('#me').attr('data-title');
alert(title);

if (title.match((Person Name) | (Email) | (Message) | (Company) | (Mobile) | (Title))) alert("It matched!");​
```

HTML:

```
<div id='me' data-title='en_Person name'>MY NAME IS FOO</div>
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aLdWD/2/

You need to wrap regular expressions in the `/` delimeter; what you had was just a syntax error.  Also you need to use the `i` modifier to ignore case (you had "Person name" in the title but "Person Name" in the expression).  The parentheses don't add anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a proper regex in your argument to `String.match`:

```
if (title.match(/Person Name|Email|Message|Company|Mobile|Title/)) {
    alert("It matched!");
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/aLdWD/3/